# Keep track of appended image in D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I am appending an image of a spinner to an icon on a particular event:

```
if (d.state == "0") {
    d3.select(this).append("svg:image")
    .attr("class", "circle")
    .attr("id", this.name)
    .attr("xlink:href", "Images/icons/ajax-loader.gif")
    .attr("x", "+16px")
    .attr("y", "-16px")
    .attr("width", "20px")
    .attr("height", "20px");
} else if (d.state == "1") {
    d3.select("#" + d.name)
    .remove();
}
```

On a state change, I want to remove/hide this spinner image. How do I keep track of it?
Is there a mechanism to associate an ID with it so that I can use it later on to remove it?

I tried with IDs (as shown in the code snippet) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple ways (depends on the larger context of how you use it):

You can assign it to a variable:

```
spinner = d3.selet(this).append("svg:image")
  .attr('class', "circle")
  ...
```

and later remove it with `spinner.remove()`. The `var spinner` will have to be declared somewhere where it's accessible to all the places in your code where you use it (i.e. towards the top of the file).

---

You can assign it an id, using `.attr("id", "my_image")` and you can select it based on that id later using `d3.select("#my_image")`. Or you can select it by its class `d3.select('circle')`.

Ids won't work if you have more than one image with the same id, and with class, if there are multiple, they would all be selected unless you first `d3.select(...)` the parent of one of them.

Comment: @Natasha, how come you're using `this.name` in one place and `d.name` in another? They're supposed to be the same thing.

Comment: Yes, was just trying some stuff so it came out that way. Any ideas on the solution?

Comment: @Natasha Yeah, use `.attr("id", d.name)` — not `this.name`.